# Why is the probability of a type one error occurring the same as the significance level alpha?

Tags: probability-theory

I don't quite get why the probability of a type one error occurring is the same as the significance level alpha. I know that it has something to do with the normal curve but i don't grasp exactly what and why.

Answer (score 1):

**By definition** the probability of a Type I error **is** the significance level of the test. For a quick glossary of terms used in the discussion of hypothesis testing, please [see this.](http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/steps/glossary/hypothesis_testing.html#1err)  For a longer discussion of hypothesis testing, please see the [Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing)

There is no connection with the normal distribution.